# iOS7 QLPreviewController change navigation bar color?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, qlpreviewcontroller

How can i set the translucent property in QLPreviewController i have tried the below code but its not working

```
  QLPreviewController *previewer = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
// Set data source
[previewer setDataSource:self];
[previewer setDelegate:self];
previewer.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
[previewer setCurrentPreviewItemIndex:index];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:previewer animated:YES];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
UINavigationBar *navBar =  [UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[QLPreviewController class], nil];
[navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation-bg-ios7.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I've tried it and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 & 4 this works for me as of February 2018

```
import QuickLook

UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [QLPreviewController.self]).setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(color: primaryColor), for: .default)
```

this is the image with color func in an extension

```
extension UIImage {

    //image with color
    convenience init?(color: UIColor) {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
        color.setFill()
        path.fill()
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.init(cgImage: image!.cgImage!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Note: Only works in iOS7